# Whose grave does Amelia visit in the credits of Professor Layton and the Eternal Diva?

Tags: professor-layton, professor-layton-the-eternal-diva

During the credits of the movie *Professor Layton and the Eternal Diva,* we're shown a sequence of pictures about events following soon after the ending.  One of these pictures shows Amelia standing in front of a grave, with Professor Layton and Luke standing farther behind her.

[image: (the picture described above)]

From seeing the movie, I assumed that it's **Melina's** grave, because Amelia specifically says “I'll remember as well” near the end of the movie, after Melina departs.

But [the TvTropes page for the movie](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/ProfessorLaytonAndTheEternalDiva) claims that it's the grave of **Amelia's grandfather** instead.

> Amelia's grandfather is also implied to pass away shortly later in the credits, and Layton and Luke join her in visiting his grave.

So whose grave is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the queen chess piece on the grave, I'd have to say it's Melina's.

> **LUKE:** Professor, do you think Melina could have been a reincarnation of the queen of Ambrosia?
>
> **LAYTON:** I think she might have been, Luke. The legend was said the
> kingdom would arise once more when its beloved queen returned.

Since that just happened, it suggests that Melina *was* the queen reincarnated.